# How do I parallelize archiving of large number of directories?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
find "./$compressed_dir_name/" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d| while read file; do archive_compressed "$directory"; done
```

That works fine, but I'd like to make it work faster by executing 3 threads of `archive_compressed "$directory"`.

I could write something like `while read file; do archive_compressed "$directory" &; done`, but there are several thousand directories to process and I don't think that starting so many processes is a good idea.

Instead I'd like to limit it to 2-3 parallel processes at any moment in time

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) with the `-P` option:

```
find "./$compressed_dir_name/" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d | xargs -P3 -n1 archive_compressed
```

The `-n1` says that each invocation of the command `archive_compressed` should be passed 1 of the arguments from standard input, and `-P3` says to run 3 processes at a time.

If you want to safely handle pathnames that may contain spaces or newlines, use instead

```
find "./$compressed_dir_name/" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs --null -P3 -n1 archive_compressed
```

If you need fancier options, look into [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Note that if your task is disk-bound instead of CPU-bound, running multiple processes in parallel will probably make it slower.

Comment: `archive_compressed` is a function, and when I invoke it this way, it says that it's not found

Comment: @ArsenZahray: I see.  For this to work, you'll need to move that function into its own script; `xargs` is an external command and doesn't know anything about functions defined in the current shell.  I don't know of any simple way to get the desired effect within the shell.